# Replace variables in text: Suggestions?

Tags: java, string, variable-expansion

I'm looking for a nice template engine or short piece of code to expand Ant-like variables in a string in Java. Example:

```
String result = expand ("${firstName} ${familyName}", map);
```

It should at least support `java.util.Map` but something that can handle beans or recursive lookups or lookups in a list of maps/objects would be welcome, too.

Suggestions?

[EDIT] In reply to TofuBeer: No nesting, only valid Java identifiers within the `{}`. Anything outside of `${}` should be copied verbatim. `$$` should become ``` $``. If that's not possible ${dollar} ``` should expand to a single `$` (so you can express `15.00 $`).

Comment: Can $, { or } appear inside a ${....}?  Will the string to expand have each ${....} separated by whitespace?  Will the string to expand have characters other than whitespace and ${....}?

Comment: @TofuBeer: No nesting, only valid Java identifiers within the {}. Anything outside of ${} should be copied verbatim. $$ should become $. If that's not possible ${dollar} should expand to a single "$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[StrSubstitutor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) does pretty much what you're asking for

Answer (score 1):

use [StringTemplate](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Introduction) in order to implement `expand`:

```
void expand(String template, Map<String,String> map) {
    StringTemplate st = new StringTemplate(template);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> attribute : map) {
       st.setAttribute(attribute.getKey(), attribute.getValue());
    }

    return st.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, StringTemplate is a very good and simple engine yet flexible. I was about to post this answer when I clicked the question... Greetz,
GHad

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Freemarker och Velocity, both of them are template engines