# Eclipse: Enviroment variables values at runtime

Tags: eclipse, debugging, variables, configuration

I have a Debug Configuration in Eclipse in which I set some variables, some dependent on each other:

```
$var1=some/path
$var2=${var1}/lib
```

I want to see the value of these variables as the program runs, but I can't figure out how to do this. I expect to see something like:

```
$var1=some/path
$var2=some/path/lib
```

Comment: Eclipse is not a language.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't get the question right, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Printing the environment variables is easy:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4ItF0MFVThfxDkgp)</kbd>**

```
package so;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Map;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> getenv = System.getenv();
        for (String entry : getenv.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0}={1}", entry, getenv.get(entry)));
        }
    }

}
```

If you actually want to expand variables in string "templates", that's a different question (which I'm sure has been answered before):

- [Replace variables in text: Suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872838/replace-variables-in-text-suggestions) (the `StringTemplate` suggestion looks like it's what you want)

Comment: So the only way to see the Debug Configuration variables' values is to use` getenv()` within the project being debugged? I use these variables as arguments to jvm. There's no `-verbose` to see what ends up being passed to the jvm?

Comment: The environment is not passed as options to jvm if that's what you mean. So, you just want to see the _expanded_ values of the macro config values in your debug configuration. Aha. Well, I don't think there's a "verbose" thing indeed.